# Find if records exist for Users, rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Using a `where` statement I need to find whether or not any of my `Users` have any `Microposts`. If not the code will run and they will get an email. This is what I have, but the code is firing even to those who do have `Microposts`.

**models/user.rb**

```
def self.lazy_mailer
  User.where("created_at < ?", 24.hours.ago).where(Micropost.blank?).find_each do |user|
    UserMailer.lazy_email(user).deliver_now
  end
end
```

`Microposts` belong to `Users` and `Users` have many `Microposts`.

Comment: Calling `blank?` on a class (like Micropost) will always return `true` (because a class is never `nil` or an empty string or collection), so your second `where` is essentially doing `where(true)`.

Comment: Ahh, ok. So what would I need to do to check if a User has any Microposts in this case?

Comment: User.includes(:microposts).where( :microposts => { :user_id => nil } )